# Probability definition question

Tags: probability

If I flip a coin, I have $50\%$ chance that it will land on tails.

$1$ out of $2$ possible outcomes.

Question is simple:  Why does that statement mean the coin will land on tails one out of two flips on average?

Are we assuming "blindly" that in the long run, all possible outcomes should be repeated the same amount of time?  And therefore because we have $2$ possible outcomes and want one of it to happen, the chance is fifty: fifty, $50\%, 1$ out of $2$ on average.

I am just questioning the definition of probability (why is it defined this way: outcomes we want / all outcomes) and want to know if I understand it correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Did you learn anything about Law of large numbers?

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** defined that way *unless* there is *no bias* in the procedure which realises the outcomes.

That is:   We only measure probability by comparing *counts* of outcomes when we *know*† that all individual outcomes are equally likely.   They also have to be mutually exclusive and jointly exhaustive.

So, with the coin toss, it is not just that we have *two possible outcomes*, it is that there are: *only two unbiased outcomes possible*‡.

---

†: or at least have a justified reason to believe.

‡: according to the model of how an ideal coin toss works, anyway.

Comment: Can I ask for more clarification? All i want to know is that how do I know of I want 1 of total 6 outcomes to happen, that it has 1/6 probability? I just rewrote the question.